# Python can't find module wit ai

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, pip, wit.ai

I just coded a Facebook Chatbot running on ngninx ubuntu with pyhthon which worked perfectly until I wanted to add wit.ai to it. The code should work but I think python cant find the module wit although I added it.

Here is the console:

```
 File "/var/www/chatbot/wit.py", line 1, in <module>
 from wit import Wit
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Wit'
```

Here is the code of the wit.py:

```
from wit import Wit

access_token = "*****"
client = Wit(access_token = access_token)


def wit_response(msg):
resp = client.message(msg)
entity = None
value = None

try:
    entity = list(resp['entities'])[0]
    value = resp['entities'][entity][0]['value']
except:
    pass
return (entity, value)
```

Comment: have you installed it using pip?

Comment: yes i did: pip install -U wit and it installed correctly

Comment: try once with sudo apt-get install wit

Comment: does not work. still same error

Comment: then you can just copy below file in your project root directory, it worked for me:  
https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit/blob/master/wit/wit.py

Comment: what does the file do?

Comment: it contains all the functions related to wit. basically you are importing Wit class from wit.py file